# How to debug JavaScript modifications of hidden input field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, laravel, debugging

I've got a Laravel 5.2 Application with an Angular JS front-end. I've ran into an issue that first showed itself as a CSRF token mismatch exception. Debugging further, I've found that while the hidden input field containing the CSRF value is correctly generated and populated, sometime during page load the value is removed from DOM.

This is what the original DOM element looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="foo-bar">
```

Clearly the code that's doing the modification must be JavaScript. I tried searching for DOM-bindings relating to the input type and name, and came up blank. Similarly, seemingly no bindings that look for parent DOM elements.

I then noticed something even stranger: I can rename that field to a different 'name' attribute, even change the field type (to, say, 'text'), and the value removal still happens. I've found that any value of 21 or more characters gets wiped. A 20-character value is left alone.

I've gone through every line of custom JS code and didn't find the culprit. No references to field names or value lengths.

There are a lot of composer packages installed, lots of different vendors, and then there's the Angular stuff and jQuery UI stuff - tons of JS that I cannot reasonably search through as I've got realistically nothing to search for (can't even search for 20/21 values as `grep` turns up thousands of results).

Chrome allows me to put a breakpoint on that input element and say that the breakpoint should trigger when an attribute changes... except it doesn't trigger.

Any other ideas for how to trace the source of the problem?

Comment: I can't exactly understand what the issue is, but looks like you just want to know what's changing the value of the hidden input is that correct? try binding an event listener to the input and inspect the `event` argument.

Comment: it should be like this right? <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token}}">

Comment: @SergioAlen - yes, that's correct. I'll review jQuery's event listeners and see if there's a way for me to see everything that's bound to the element... I think I recall doing that once before. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've gone through it and there are no events bound to that element. So something is searching for it, modifying the value (removing it), and moving on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a day later I've finally figured out the problem: "Adblock Plus for YouTube" extension installed in my Chrome browser. This extension has been installed for years, but only now - randomly - started causing issues. Disabling it fixes the problem, re-enabling it re-introduces the problem.

Found by process of elimination. Still no good way to debug the problem I described.